# Optimizing ORDER BY and WHERE on sql queries with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, sql-order-by, query-optimization

I am currently working on an online e-commerce platform back-office.
I currently have around 70 000 products and I would like to speed up the display of data so that the employees can work more efficiently.

I am using MySQL "Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.28".

Basically for my back office (I will not explicitly list the details of the columns because I don't think it really matters), I have:

- A main table `node_node` containing basic information for all data like `creation_date`, `last_modification_date` for example (date fields)
- A main table `staff_node_staffnode` containing basic information for all data created by employees (like products, brands, etc ...). It contains mainly the fields `owner_id` (foreign key to the staff table that I will not detail here) and `is_verified` (boolean field) and a foreign key `staffnode_ptr_id` poiting to `node_node`
- Data structure tables like `product_merchandise`, `product_brand` which contain their own fields and a foreign key `staffnode_ptr_id` poiting to `staff_node_staffnode`

I first run a query to retrieve all the IDs of the products I want to display (given the large amount of data I prefer first retrieving only the ids of the product of my list which will be limited to 30 per page, and then on this subset retrieve more data with more joins on other tables)

```
SELECT id from product_merchandise pm 
INNER JOIN staff_node_staffnode sns ON sns.node_ptr_id = pm.staffnode_ptr_id 
INNER JOIN node_node nn ON nn.id = sns.node_ptr_id 
ORDER BY creation_date DESC LIMIT 30;
```

There is an index on `product_merchandise(staffnode_ptr_id)` and `staff_node_staffnode(node_ptr_id)` and `node_node(id)`.
It takes between 2 and 3 seconds on average to run this query which is too long.

EDIT: as suggested in the comments, here is the output of the EXPLAIN query. EXPLAIN ANALYZE is not working on my Mysql version.

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+------------------------------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key                          | key_len | ref                    | rows  | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+------------------------------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pm    | NULL       | index  | PRIMARY       | product_merchandise_447d3092 | 5       | NULL                   | 69623 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sns   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY                      | 4       | db.pm.staffnode_ptr_id |     1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | nn    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY                      | 4       | db.pm.staffnode_ptr_id |     1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+------------------------------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I decided to add an index `creation_date_idx` on `node_node(creation_date)` and when I force the use of it, I get between 0.10s and 0.15s, which is perfect:

```
SELECT id from product_merchandise pm 
INNER JOIN staff_node_staffnode sns ON sns.node_ptr_id = pm.staffnode_ptr_id 
INNER JOIN node_node nn FORCE INDEX(creation_date_idx) ON nn.id = sns.node_ptr_id 
ORDER BY creation_date DESC LIMIT 30;
```

The problem now is that the staff working on the products should be able to filter according to different parameters, for example `owner_id`.

```
SELECT id from product_merchandise pm 
INNER JOIN staff_node_staffnode sns ON sns.node_ptr_id = pm.staffnode_ptr_id 
INNER JOIN node_node nn FORCE INDEX(creation_date_idx) ON nn.id = sns.node_ptr_id 
WHERE sns.owner_id = [NUMBER]
ORDER BY creation_date DESC LIMIT 30;
```

The result is terrible (I stopped the query around 30s but I assume it could have taken much more time) and it makes sense because I force the use of the index `creation_date_index` which is not relevant here.

If I remove the use of this index, I get better results (1-2 s.) but I come back to the first issue which is: the calculation time is too long.

EDIT: as suggested, here is the output of the EXPLAIN for

```
SELECT id from product_merchandise pm 
INNER JOIN staff_node_staffnode sns ON sns.node_ptr_id = pm.staffnode_ptr_id 
INNER JOIN node_node nn ON nn.id = sns.node_ptr_id 
WHERE sns.owner_id = [NUMBER]
ORDER BY creation_date DESC LIMIT 30;
```

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                         | key                          | key_len | ref                    | rows  | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pm    | NULL       | index  | PRIMARY                               | product_merchandise_447d3092 | 5       | NULL                   | 69220 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sns   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,staff_node_staffnode_5e7b1936 | PRIMARY                      | 4       | db.pm.staffnode_ptr_id |     1 |    19.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | nn    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                               | PRIMARY                      | 4       | db.pm.staffnode_ptr_id |     1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I guess I should create another index but I don't really know on what columns.
Moreover, the staff should be able to filter on 5 different fields (let's say they are all VARCHAR or FOREIGN KEY or BOOLEAN) and order by this different fields as well. Those fields could be from the table `product_merchandise` (product_name for example) or `staff_node_staffnode` (creator or is_verified) or event `node_node` (creation_date for example).

I hope I made myself clear enough.
Thank you for your time, I would appreciate any help !

Have a great day.

Comment: you have to share your execution plan for your slow query

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by execution plan ? Do you want me to use the EXPLAIN sql fonction ?

Comment: yes `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

Comment: Ok I added EXPLAIN as you suggested. EXPLAIN ANALYZE doesn't work with the version of MySQL I have (Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.28). Also, I used EXPLAIN only on the first query and not the one exceeding 30s because I didn't think it was relevant.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables.  Then we can discuss what extra indexes you may need.

Answer (score 0):

I put it here since it doean't fit in comments ,
here is the list of indexes you need to improve your performance:

- product_merchandise(id,staffnode_ptr_id)
- staff_node_staffnode(node_ptr_id,owner_id)
- node_node(id,creation_date DESC)

change/add your indexes to above list and let's see how it change the performance

Comment: Ok thank you very much I will test this and post my answer with the result

Answer (score 0):

Thank you eshirvana for your suggestion.
I post an answer instead of editing my original question because the results of my tests are quite long. I hope this will not be a problem.

First of all I forgot to mention that `staffnode_ptr_id` was the primary key of `product_merchandise` and that `node_ptr_id` was the primary key of `staff_node_staffnode`.

Then here are the indexes I have besides the PRIMARY indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX node_creationdate_idx ON node_node(creation_date);
CREATE INDEX node_id_creationdate_idx ON node_node(id,creation_date);
CREATE INDEX staffnode_nodeptrid_ownerid_idx ON staff_node_staffnode(node_ptr_id,owner_id);
```

I didn't specify the DESC for the index `node_id_creationdate_idx` because the ordering could be ASC or DESC depending the cases.

**Here are the results of the speed tests I ran (I executed the queries 10 times for each case):**

[The details can be found on this link](https://staticfiles.me/storage/fsdf84651sogrtn51.txt)

```
No index forced, ordering by 'creation_date' only
average: 2.4473010037094354 fastest: 2.0254166573286057 slowest: 2.891202986240387

Forcing index 'node_creationdate_idx', ordering by 'creation_date' only
average: 0.045951709523797034 fastest: 0.03917844220995903 slowest: 0.06625311821699142

No index forced, ordering by 'creation_date' and filtering on 'owner_id'
average: 1.7595138054341077 fastest: 1.08128846809268 slowest: 2.858897101134062

Forcing index 'node_creationdate_idx', ordering by 'creation_date' and filtering on 'owner_id'
average: infinity
```

The results above correspond to what I was stating in my original post.

If I try ordering by `sku` which is a VARCHAR column of the `product_merchandise` table, the calculation is very fast no matter what

```
No index forced, ordering by 'sku' only
average: 0.0022248398512601853 fastest: 0.0017771385610103607 slowest: 0.0032510906457901

No index forced, ordering by 'sku' and filtering on 'owner_id'
average: 0.00639396645128727 fastest: 0.0025643371045589447 slowest: 0.0197000615298748
```

On the results below, I tried to force the use of the new indexes `staffnode_nodeptrid_ownerid_idx` and `node_id_creationdate_idx`

```
Forcing index 'staffnode_nodeptrid_ownerid_idx', ordering by 'creation_date' only
average: 2.1846631478518246 fastest: 1.665839608758688 slowest: 2.5894345454871655

Forcing index 'staffnode_nodeptrid_ownerid_idx', ordering by 'creation_date' and filtering on 'owner_id'
average: 0.9459988728165627 fastest: 0.726978026330471 slowest: 1.1611059792339802

Forcing index 'node_id_creationdate_idx', ordering by 'creation_date' only
average: 1.7628929097205401 fastest: 1.5384734570980072 slowest: 1.9222845435142517

Forcing index 'node_id_creationdate_idx', ordering by 'creation_date' and filtering on 'owner_id'
average: 1.2311949148774146 fastest: 0.9017647355794907 slowest: 1.4749027229845524

Forcing indexes 'node_id_creationdate_idx' and 'staffnode_nodeptrid_ownerid_idx', ordering by 'creation_date' only
average: 1.5638799782842399 fastest: 1.3537045568227768 slowest: 1.8629941195249557

Forcing indexes 'node_id_creationdate_idx' and 'staffnode_nodeptrid_ownerid_idx', ordering by 'creation_date' and filtering on 'owner_id'
average: 1.6410113696008921 fastest: 1.2819141708314419 slowest: 2.3169863671064377
```

In conclusion:

- I get slightly better results with those indexes, although it's still too long in my opinion
- It seems that the problem lies in the fact that `creation_date` does not belong to the table `product_merchandise` and therefore indexing on it is not really efficient

What do you suggest ? Should I change the structure of my tables ?

Thank you for your help !